# Pi3 B+ FFMPEG encode x265 very slow

Tags: pi-3b+, ffmpeg

I just bought a RPI3 B+ with the hopes of using it as a media encoding box. I built ffmpeg, and use the following to transcode media from h264 to h265

`ffmpeg -i "$i" -c:v libx265 -crf 28 -c:a aac -b:a 128k -preset slow output.mp4`

The issue is that regardless of what I use as the preset, it runs at about 1 FPS. Is there any way to speed it up, or is it just a limitation of the RPI?

Comment: I'd say that's a limitation of the RPi - I've never been able to get better than about 1.5fps on a Pi1 with h265

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Raspberry Pi has **no** accelerators for H.265. The Raspberry Pi **can** accelerate **H.264** in both directions (encode/decode) by default.

ffmpeg calls the accelerated decoder "h264_mmal" and  the accelerated encoder "h264_omx". Not all versions of ffmpeg support them, but the one in Raspbian Stretch should.

I have not seen any benchmarks *in the context of ffmpeg*. Benchmark results would be **very** interesting ....